# what is the best way to use 'enum' and 'Date' in POJO class? and how to do validation in POJO class for employee?

Tags: java, mysql, enums, pojo

As you can see i am using 'enum' in employee_detail as well as in gender.java.
Here is my pojo class and enum class:
//Employee.java

```
package com.myp.ems.model;
import com.myp.ems.model.Gender;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class Employee{   

    private int empId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String emailId;
    private Date dob;
    private Gender gender;
    private double salary;
    private long contact_no;
    private String occupation;
    private String designation;
    private Date doj; 

    /**
    * Setter Methods
    */

    public void setEmpId(int empId){
        this.empId = empId;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName){
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName){
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public void setEmailID(String emailId){
        this.emailId = emailId;
    }

    public void setDOB(Date dob){
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public void setGender(Gender gender){
        gender = gender;
    }

    public void setSalary(double salary){
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public void setContactNumber(long contact_no){
        this.contact_no = contact_no;
    }

    public void setoccupation(String occupation){
        this.occupation = occupation;
    }

    public void setDesignation(String designation){
        this.designation = designation;
    }

    public void setDOJ(Date doj){
        this.doj = doj;
    }

    /**
    * Getter Methods
    */
    public int getEmpId(){
        return empId;        
    }

    public String getFirstName(){
        return firstName;        
    }

    public String getLastName(){
        return lastName;        
    }

    public String getEmailId(){
        return emailId;        
    }    

    public Date getDOB(){
        return dob;        
    }

    public Gender getGender(){
        return gender;        
    }

    public double getSalary(){
        return salary;        
    }

    public long getContactNumber(){
        return contact_no;        
    }

    public String getOccupation(){
        return occupation;        
    }

    public String getDesignation(){
        return designation;        
    }

    public Date getDOJ(){
        return doj;        
    }      
}
```

//Gender.java :

```
package com.myp.ems.model;

import java.util.Enumeration;

public enum Gender{
    Male, Female, Transgender;
}
```

//Employee.sql :

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE_DETAIL(
    EMP_ID INT(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    FIRST_NAME  VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    LAST_NAME   VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    EMAIL_ID    VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    EMP_DOB     DATE NOT NULL,
    GENDER ENUM('MALE','FEMALE','TRANSGENDER'),
    EMP_SALARY  DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
    CONTACT_NO  BIGINT (10)  NOT NULL,
    OCCUPATION  VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    DESIGNATION VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    DATE_OF_JOINING DATE NOT NULL
);
```

Can any one tell what is wrong with that program and table and please provide me best solution to overcome from that.or is there any other possible way to make my program best??

Comment: What framework are you using to connect the SQL to the POJO? Is it Ibatis?  Is it Hibernate?

Comment: No, I am not using any framework , i am implementing it in just CORE JAVA . I'm using "dbconnection.java"directly. @ProgrammersBlock